# Build vocabulary representations python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, vocabulary

I have a list of strings of this form:

```
['1---d--e--g--gh','1---c---e--gh--', '1---ghj--h--h--', '1---g--gkk--h--', '1---d--dfe---fg', '1---c--d--dh--j', '1---f--gh--h--h', '1---fg-hg-hh-fg', '1---d--cd7--d--', '1---gghG--g77--', '1---hkj--kl--l-', '1---gged--ghjg-', '1---kk--k--k---', '1---gjklk--khgl', '1---c---d---dh-', '1---g---ghkk--k', '1---fH---h--g--', '1---f--gij---hj', '1---g--ghg---g-', '1---c---dc--cf-', '1---d---e--gh--', '1---l--lmnmlk-l', '1---d77---c--d-', '1---kj--k--lk-l', '1---g---gd--e--', '1---hhgh--d---h', '1---f--f---h---', '1---g--gkh-jkhg', '1---fg-hgh-fhfg', '1---k-k--klkj--', '1---g--l--kjhg-', 'gh--g---gh--g--', '1---f--df--fhij', '1---g--g--g---g', '1---g---gh-kh--', '1---g---gk--h--']
```

I want to create vocabulary representations of 3 types : `a`, `b`, `c`.

`a` are separated by at least one dash `-`, `b` by at least two `--`, and `c` by at least three dashes `---`.

For example, `1--d--d--dfd-dc---f---g--ghgf-ghg-hj--h` should give:

```
a: {d, d, dfd, dc, f, g, ghgf, ghg, hj, h}
b: {d, d, dfd-dc, f, g, ghgf-ghg-hj, h}
c: {d--d--dfd-dc, f, g--ghgf-ghg-hj--h}
```

As vocabulary representations (we skip the `1` in the beginning). Does anyone know a way to do that in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension for each string in the list:

```
string = '1--d--d--dfd-dc---f---g--ghgf-ghg-hj--h'
a = [i.strip("-") for i in string.split("-") if i and i.strip("-")!='1']
b = [i.strip("-") for i in string.split("--") if i and i.strip("-")!='1']
c = [i.strip("-") for i in string.split("---") if i and i.strip("-")!='1']
```

If you have a list `vps` containings those strings, you can just do:

```
l =[[i.strip("-") for i in string.split("-") if i and i.strip("-")!='1'] for string in vps]
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer. one more question, if my list name is `vps`, i will simply do `a = [i.strip("-") for i in vps.items[1:].split("-") if i != ""]` ?

Comment: Do you want it to return a list containing all the different string lists?

Comment: I think this fails the test case `gh--g---gh--g--`

Comment: I want each vocabulary to contain all different representations of its type, so yes I want to iterate over all string items in the list and get the results

Comment: updated answer @joasa

Answer (score 1):

Using example use case:

```py
string = "1--d--d--dfd-dc---f---g--ghgf-ghg-hj--h"

def vocab_representation(string):
    import re
    letter_dict = {}
    # remove leading 1 and -, remove trailing -
    string = re.sub(r'^1?-*(.*\w).*$', r'\1', string)
    letter_dict['a'] = [x for x in string.split("-") if x]
    # No words with leading -
    letter_dict['b'] = [x for x in string.split("--") if (x and x[0] != '-')]
    # No words with leading -
    letter_dict['c'] = c = [x for x in string.split("---") if (x and x[0] != '-')]
    return letter_dict
res = vocab_representation(string)
```

Output:

```py
{
 'a': ['d', 'd', 'dfd', 'dc', 'f', 'g', 'ghgf', 'ghg', 'hj', 'h'],
 'b': ['d', 'd', 'dfd-dc', 'ghgf-ghg-hj', 'h'],
 'c': ['d--d--dfd-dc', 'f', 'g--ghgf-ghg-hj--h']
}
```

Using more complex test case:

```py
string = "gh--g---gh--g--"
res = vocab_representation(string)
```

Output:

```py
{
 'a': ['gh', 'g', 'gh', 'g'],
 'b': ['gh', 'g', 'g'],
 'c': ['gh--g', 'gh--g']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = ['1--d--d--dfd-dc---f---g--ghgf-ghg-hj--h']

a = []
b = []
c = []

def go():    
    for line in lines:
        line = line[1:]
        line = line.strip('-')
        global a, b, c
        a = line.split('-')
        b = line.split('--')
        c = line.split('---')

def sanitize():
    global a, b

    tmpa = []
    for s in a:
        if s != '':
            tmpa.append(s.strip('-'))

    tmpb = []
    for s in b:
        if s != '':
            tmpb.append(s.strip('-'))

    a = tmpa
    b = tmpb

go()
sanitize()
print("a: {" + ', '.join(a) + "}")
print("b: {" + ', '.join(b) + "}")
print("c: {" + ', '.join(c) + "}")
```